# Dealing with json null in python

Tags: python, json, api, null

I am trying to get some data from a trading API in the web. The data are returned in a JSON format as shown below and my program is written in python:

```
{ "result": [ {
        "name": "ALGOBEAR/USD",
        "enabled": true,
        "postOnly": false,
        "priceIncrement": 1e-08,
        "sizeIncrement": 1000000000000.0,
        "minProvideSize": 1000000000000.0,
        "last": 1e-08,
        "bid": null,
        "ask": null,
        "price": null,
        "type": "spot",
        "futureType": null,
        "baseCurrency": "ALGOBEAR",
        "isEtfMarket": true,
        "quoteCurrency": "USD",
        "underlying": null,
        "restricted": false,
        "highLeverageFeeExempt": true,
        "largeOrderThreshold": 350.0,
        "change1h": 0.0,
        "change24h": 0.0,
        "changeBod": 0.0,
        "quoteVolume24h": 0.0,
        "volumeUsd24h": 0.0,
        "priceHigh24h": 0.0,
        "priceLow24h": 0.0
    }]}
```

In this list there are over 500 of similar dictionaries as the above. The problem is that  the `null` values that are returned e.g. `"price": null` cannot be compared with the float values of prices(if they are equal, bigger or smaller) of other dictionaries e.g `"price": 0.00019845` and the program returns an error.

I would like to ask if there is a way to deal with these `null` values so that the python programme can identify them. For example if there is a way to transform them into `None` so that python can deal with them or delete the dictionaries in the list above that contain `null` values from the beginning using maybe a `json` method.

Thanks!

Comment: When you parse the JSON they should be turned into `None` automatically. What are you getting instead when you call `json.loads()`?

Comment: In Python 3, `None` can't be compared greater or less than float values, because it's not any sort of number. How do you want to "deal with" the nulls? How are you trying to "deal with" them? Could you [edit] your post to include the code you tried and the error you received?

Comment: @Barmar i am using this line to get the JSON from the API `FtxData = requests.get(url).json()` and after i call the `json.loads()`  `FtxInfo = json.loads(FtxData)` and i get this error ` TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict` for the the call of the `json.loads()`

Comment: You don't need to call `json.loads()` explicitly. The `.json()` method does that for you. So how are you seeing the result you show in the question?

Comment: If you do `print(FixData)` you should see `None` where all the `null` are in the JSON.

Comment: @Barmar to print `Fixdata` i used `print(json.dumps(FtxData, indent=4))` maybe this is the problem why i see null and not `None`?

Comment: `json.dumps()` converts the Python `None` back into JSON `null`.

Comment: Compare `print(None)` with `print(json.dumps(None))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `null` values become `None` automatically when loaded using the `json` module in the Python standard library.

```py
import json
content = '["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]'
data = json.loads(content)
print(data)
# ['foo', {'bar': ['baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
```

See [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).